# How can I know which port is available in node if I wan to use NodePort in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to specify port when using NodePort, but how can I know which port is available on all nodes, I don't want to port conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Right approach is to let Kubernetes choose the `nodePort` automatically from the default allocated range(30000–32767). Don't include `nodePort` in your yaml.

Comment: The problem is I'd like to get this port and tell other external processes, and then other process can communicate with this pod. Or is there anyway to know which port is allocated when my pod is started ?

Comment: @zjffdu not sure

Comment: @zjffdu may be you can have additional service meant for these external processes and targeting the pods that would do the required work

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the services using

`kubectl get svc --all-namespaces`

Then you can `grep` using the type.

There you can see all the assigned ports. It's basic piping and output filtering.

`kubectl get svc --all-namespaces | grep ClusterIP | while read -r _ _ _ _ _ port _; do echo "$port" ; done`

Answer (score 0):

You could get all services, grep node port and see what comes out.

```
$ kubectl get services --all-namespaces -o yaml |grep "nodePort:"|sort
  nodePort: 30215
  nodePort: 30274
  nodePort: 30312
  nodePort: 30342
  nodePort: 30344
  nodePort: 30386
  nodePort: 30517
  nodePort: 30738
  nodePort: 30863
  nodePort: 31063
  nodePort: 31162
  nodePort: 31445
```

Or pipe to jq with json output if you want a more elaborate listing with service names and so on.

Edit: the port range for node ports is normally 30000-32767 and should be reserved for Kubernetes use to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You could do `netstat | grep <port>` .

If you set the type field to NodePort, the Kubernetes control plane will allocate a port from a range specified by --service-node-port-range flag (default: 30000-32767). Each node will proxy that port each (the same port number on every Node) into your Service.